# How can I teach vim about additional C language types for syntax highlighting?

Tags: c, vim, types, vim-syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting works swimmingly beautiful with the standard types, like `int`, `uint32_t`, `float` and so on. However, I would like to teach vim that there are other types defined with typedef in my code, e.g.

```
typedef double float64_t;
```

How can I make vim use the same highlighting for `float64_t` as for the standard types? A solution with a local file (e.g. within my `~/.vimrc` or `.vim` directory) would be preferred. Automatic parsing of typedef names not a requirement, I'm willing to add typedef names as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to add the names as needed.

For Windows, create (replace `vimfiles` as appropriate)

```
~\vimfiles\after\syntax\c.vim
```

and add lines defining new syntax highlighting items.  For example (from my `cpp.vim`),

```
" add nullptr as a keyword for highlighting
syn keyword Constant nullptr
```

To determine which group you want to add to, open a c file and type `:syntax` and you can look through the existing syntax groups.

Comment: If you just want to choose the color, :hl may be easier for your eyes to parse than :syntax

Comment: By convention, the syntax groups should start with the filetype name, e.g. `cType`, `cConstant`.

Comment: Good comments. Just wanted to add that, in my `vim` build at least, `:hl` is not a command by default and I have to use `:highlight`

Comment: In my specific case, for typedef names, the command is `syntax keyword Type float64_t`.

Answer (score 4):

I also found out that we can use the `match` command to cover a set of typedef names described by a pattern:

```
match Type /\w*_t/
```

will highlight as a type all typedef names ending in `_t` (but will do so everywhere, even inside comments and string literals.)

Comment: This solution also highlights part of identifier names. For  instance if  I write `my_test_function`, the  `my_t` part will be highlighted. Do you happen to  have a fix for that? EDIT: `/\w*_t\s/` seems to work.

Comment: @sunmat Yes, that's what happens like I stated as a parenthetical remark. If you append \s the that will not work when a tab is next, or EOL. You might want to adjust your pattern accordingly.

Comment: `\<` and `\>` can be used to anchor a pattern at beginning and end of a word.

Answer (score 1):

You can match only those identifiers *ending* with `_t` (not those that contain `_t` partway through like `foo_table`) by using *negative lookahead*.

Place in `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`:

```
syn match cType "\h\w*_t\w\@!"
```

`\h` (head of word) means the same as `[A-Za-z_]` i.e. it will match any character that can start an identifier in C.  `\w*` (word) means the same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]*` i.e. it will match any characters that can continue an identifier in C.  `_t` will literally match those two characters.  `\w\@!` is negative lookahead: it will match as long as `\w` does not match i.e. it will match as long as the `_t` is not followed by an alphanumeric character or an underscore.

Note: This is subtly different to `\h\w*_t\W` which will match a `foobar_t` type followed by something other than `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, which means it won't match at the end of the line or end of the file.  That pattern will also match and highlight as a keyword that following character, which is definitely not what you want.

Comment: Just looked this up and found my own answer. D'oh!